# Neither of undefined, implementation defined, unspecifed behavior

Tags: c++, unspecified-behavior

C++03

> $5.3.3/2 - "The size of a most derived
>   class shall be greater than zero
>   (1.8)."
>
> $1.8/4 - "Unless it is a bit-field
>   (9.6), a most derived object shall
>   have a non-zero size and shall occupy
>   one or more bytes of storage."

My question then is:

Is the size of an empty class unspecified, implemention defined? Is it supposed to be documented by the compiler documentation? Those two quotes leave it so open ended as far as my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 4):

It's unspecified (except that it must be greater than 0). It's not implementation defined, either (so it doesn't need to be documented).

I'm not sure why an implementation would use any size other than 1 for an empty class (assuming by "empty class" we're talking about a class that doesn't even derive from another class), but I suppose it could.

---

To address Chubsdad's question about what determines that this is unspecified behavior (as opposed to implementation defined):

The standard defines "unspecified behavior" as:

> behavior, for a well-formed program construct and correct data, that depends on the implementation. The
>   implementation is not required to document which behavior occurs.

It defines "implementation-defined behavior" as:

> behavior, for a well-formed program construct and correct data, that depends on the implementation and
>   that each implementation shall document

So the only difference between the two is that implementation-defined behavior must be documented.  The standard will say when behavior must be documented (usually by saying that a behavior is implementation-defined)

Unfortunately, the standard doesn't always directly state that a behavior is unspecified (or undefined). So, some analysis is in order:

Since the standard says:

- that `sizeof` must evaluate to a greater-than-zero result for an empty class,
- doesn't say what that value must be (other than greater-than-zero)
- doesn't say that the value must be documented (or that it's implementation-defined)

by a process of elimination, the sizeof an empty class is unspecified.

The possible problem with this analysis (and with much analysis of something as complex as the C++ standard) is that there's the possibility that there's some other corner of the standard that I've missed that might require the sizeof an empty class be some specific value. And that requirement might be by inference (or would it be deduction?) from some other rules; it might not be stated outright. It's not always easy to track down all the areas of the standard that might apply to a particular issue.

If that's the case, then someone will hopefully note that and shoot my argument down.

Comment: Class and struct layouts are typically padded to the machine word size, so a size of 4 seems more likely on typical architectures.

Comment: How do we reach that conclusion is my question? It is soooo open ended to my mind

Comment: It's specified to be non-zero. :)

Comment: @karl: that seems reasonable. I think it's been 1 when I've examined the size of an empty class, but it's been a long time and probably only on one compiler, so small sample size might skew my results. I might even be remembering wrong...

Comment: So if it is specified to be non zero, then it can't be unspecified behavior, meaning it is implementation defined. Then it should be documented

Comment: I don't understand why this is causing a problem for you. Legally, the size may be anything greater than zero. Legally, it is not required to be any particular value, except that it must not be zero. Practically, it will be as small as possible, because there is no reason to make it any larger.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: It does not create any problem as such, but I want to understand what the interpretation should be given the fact that it is not very clear to me if is unspecified or implementation defined behavior. And what other better place than SO. I find similar interpretations possible in other places in the Standard.

Comment: @Chubsdad: I added some detail about why this is unspecified rather than implementation defined.

Comment: You're mixing two issues. The requirement that "size must be greater than zero" is obviously not unspecified. It is stated clearly in the standard. But it is still unspecified exactly what the size should be. As long as it satisfies this constraint, it is legal, and does not need to be documented.

Comment: Would there be any requirement that an implementation have any form of consistency?  Would anything forbid an implementation from making empty classes whose names started with a-q take one byte, those whose names start with r-y take two bytes, and those whose names start with z take 47 bytes?

Answer (score 1):

Most derived type means the class of a complete object of a class type (1.8 of the C++ standard (intro.object)). So an empty class that is instantiated must have a unique address, which implies that `sizeof(empty class)>0`. However, this also means that you can have a base class of zero size (also in 1.8 of the C++ standard).

So if you have to instantiate an empty class, it cannot have a size of zero. If it is a base class subobject, then it can have zero size.

Comment: That case of 0 is called a subobject in Standard parlance IMO. My doubt is about the most derived object